# How to check if a set of coordinates is in a list

Tags: python

I am very new to programming, but I thought it would be fun to try and program Langton's ant. For those of you that don't know, it's an ant that walks around on a board. When it hits a red square, it turns right and colors the red square white, and when it hits a white square it turns left, coloring the previous white square red. With my very primitive knowledge of programming, I came up with this program:

```
def Move(direction):
    global x
    global y
    if direction % 4 == 0:
        y += 1
    elif direction % 4 == 1:
        x += 1
    elif direction % 4 == 2:
        y -= 1
    else:
        x -= 1

Lred = []
Lwhite = []
# To make sure the program recognizes the squares as being white initially.
for i in range(-4, 5):
    for i2 in range(-4, 5):
        Lwhite.append([i2,i])

x = 0
y = 0
direct = 0

# Here I try to make the first 10 steps.
for i in range(10):
    print [x,y]
    if [x,y] in Lred:
        Lred.remove([x,y])
        Lwhite.append([x,y])
        direct-=1
    if [x,y] in Lwhite:
        print "white square"
        Lwhite.remove([x,y])
        Lred.append([x,y])
        direct+=1
    Move(direct)
print Lwhite
print Lred
```

As you can see when you run this program, it says the square is white the second time it hits [0,0], but when it started, it should have coloured it red. [0,0] is in the list of red square that is printed in the end, and it is not in the list of white squares. Which is what i wanted.

But why does it still consider the "if [x,y] in Lwhite" statement to be true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everytime your ant hits a sqaure, it checks whether it is red. If it is red, it makes the square white and rotates the ant. Then, it checks if the square is white, **which is always true because if it were red then the previous step made it white**. Using an `elif` statement instead of a `if` statement would fix this.

```
# Here I try to make the first 10 steps.
for i in range(10):
    print [x,y]
    if [x,y] in Lred:
        Lred.remove([x,y])
        Lwhite.append([x,y])
        direct-=1
    elif [x,y] in Lwhite:
        print "white square"
        Lwhite.remove([x,y])
        Lred.append([x,y])
        direct+=1
    Move(direct)
print Lwhite
print Lred
```